# Bar chart in ggplot is dropping first and last value

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to create a very simple bar chart.
Here the variables and data I want to plot (please, not that although it is a time series, the x variable is not a date but and ordered factor):

> ```
>       Wave         value 
>     Spring 2015    0,33
>     Autumn 2015    0,25
>     Spring 2016    0,25
>     Autumn 2016    0,26  
>     Spring 2017    0,38 
>     Autumn 2017    0,43 
>     Spring 2018    0,38
>     Autumn 2018    0,25
>     Spring 2019    0,24
>     Autumn 2019    0,19
>     Spring 2020    0,10 
>     Autumn 2020    0,50
> ```

And here is the very simple code in ggplot that i'm using to plot these values:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x= Wave, y=value))+ geom_bar(  stat="identity")+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5))
```

Everything works fine (it is a really basic plot) expect that the first and the last value of the series are not plotted.

[The first bar in the plot is "Autumn 2015" (whereas the first value in the data i have is "Spring 2015") and the last value in the graph is "spring 2020" (whereas in my dataset I've also "Autumn 2020").](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxoqz.png)

I understand form past posts on a similar issue, that I need to expand the x axis, and indeed this code solves the issue:

```
ggplot(Graphs, aes(x= Wave, y=`More optimistic`))+  geom_bar(  stat="identity")+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5))+   scale_x_discrete(limits= c("Spring 2015", "Autumn 2015", "Spring 2016", "Autumn 2016", "Spring 2017", "Autumn 2017", "Spring 2018", "Autumn 2018", "Spring 2019", "Autumn 2019", "Spring 2020", "Autumn 2020"))
```

However that is quite cumbersome and requires a lot of writing.

Anyone knows:

1. why I have this issue (the series is not extremely long!)
2. is there a more elegant way to solve the issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because it is a factor, the x-axis gets ordered by the factor value and not by order of appearance or alphabetically. What you are doing when you provide a limits vector to `scale_x_discrete` you are essentially manually overriding the sorting by factor level. This has nothing to do with expanding the x-axis.

Comment: You could try to replace `scale_x_discrete(limits= c("Spring 2015", "Autumn 2015", [...]` with `scale_x_discrete(limits= sort(Wave))`. I can't test unless you provide your data using `dput()`.

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for you suggestion. However, i do not understand your answer completely, as the problem is not that i get the variable sorted in the wrong order, but that i do not get two data points ("spring 2015" at the beginning of the series. and "Autumn 2020" a the end) plotted at all in the graph.

Comment: As a follow up, indeed sorting the factor variable anew worked! Thanks a lot. Still I'd like to understand what is the reason linking the "sorting" of the variable with the fact that two values are not plotted at all...

Comment: You are missing no data on the plot you supplied, it's just in a different order to that you thought you supplied.

Answer (score 1):

Just about every question on SO that includes the [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) tag and asks about the order of labels is resolved with one of two things: (1) convert to a number (when it's a number-like thing in a string that should be numeric), or (2) convert to a `factor` and explicitly control its `levels=`. If your `Wave` variable had months in it, then we could deal with it as a `Date` (number-like, category 1 above). Since not, though, you can explicitly control the order in a vector, then we should go with option 2. Since you know the candidate seasons (`"Spring"` comes before `"Autumn"`, and `"2018"` before `"2019"`, for example), we can programmatically enforce ordering.

In case your number has (1) more than one observation per `Wave`, perhaps for stacked barplots, or (2) they are not inherently ordered, here's one technique for ensuring that they are in the correct order. First, I'll intentionally unorder them to prove the method (Obviously, you don't need this step in your solution.)

```r
set.seed(2021)
data <- data[sample(seq_len(nrow(data))),]
data
#           Wave value
# 7  Spring 2018  0.38
# 6  Autumn 2017  0.43
# 10 Autumn 2019  0.19
# 12 Autumn 2020  0.50
# 4  Autumn 2016  0.26
# 8  Autumn 2018  0.25
# 11 Spring 2020  0.10
# 3  Spring 2016  0.25
# 2  Autumn 2015  0.25
# 9  Spring 2019  0.24
# 1  Spring 2015  0.33
# 5  Spring 2017  0.38
```

Determine all possible `Wave` values *in order*:

```r
W <- unique(data$Wave)
order(gsub("[^0-9]", "", W), match(gsub("\\s[0-9]+", "", W), c("Spring", "Autumn")))
#  [1] 11  9  8  5 12  2  1  6 10  3  7  4
W <- W[order(gsub("[^0-9]", "", W), match(gsub("\\s[0-9]+", "", W), c("Spring", "Autumn")))]
W
#  [1] "Spring 2015" "Autumn 2015" "Spring 2016" "Autumn 2016" "Spring 2017" "Autumn 2017" "Spring 2018" "Autumn 2018"
#  [9] "Spring 2019" "Autumn 2019" "Spring 2020" "Autumn 2020"
```

Change to a `factor` and plot.

```r
data$Wave <- factor(data$Wave, levels = W)
# unchanged
ggplot(data, aes(x= Wave, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image: ggplot2 with ordered x-axis]

Interesting benefit of using `factor`s: the data itself does not have to be ordered for the order of the levels to be effective. For example, after the code above, `data` is *still* unordered.

```r
head(data)
#           Wave value
# 7  Spring 2018  0.38
# 6  Autumn 2017  0.43
# 10 Autumn 2019  0.19
# 12 Autumn 2020  0.50
# 4  Autumn 2016  0.26
# 8  Autumn 2018  0.25
data <- data[order(data$Wave),]
head(data)
#          Wave value
# 1 Spring 2015  0.33
# 2 Autumn 2015  0.25
# 3 Spring 2016  0.25
# 4 Autumn 2016  0.26
# 5 Spring 2017  0.38
# 6 Autumn 2017  0.43
```

---

Data

```r
data <- structure(list(Wave = c("Spring 2015", "Autumn 2015", "Spring 2016", "Autumn 2016", "Spring 2017", "Autumn 2017", "Spring 2018", "Autumn 2018", "Spring 2019", "Autumn 2019", "Spring 2020", "Autumn 2020"), value = c(0.33, 0.25, 0.25, 0.26, 0.38, 0.43, 0.38, 0.25, 0.24, 0.19, 0.1, 0.5)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace `scale_x_discrete(limits= c("Spring 2015", "Autumn 2015", [...]` with `scale_x_discrete(limits= sort(Wave))`.

I can't test unless you provide your data using `dput()`.